# How can I initialize a nested map inside a struct in Go?

Tags: go

If I have a nested map variable like this inside a struct:

```
type someStruct struct {
    nestedMap map[int]map[string]string
}

var ss = someStruct {
    nestedMap: make(map[int]map[string]string),
}
```

This does not work and does a runtime error.

How do I initialize it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to make the child maps as well.

```
func (s *someStruct) Set(i int, k, v string) {
    child, ok := s.nestedMap[i]
    if !ok {
        child = map[string]string{}
        s.nestedMap[i] = child
    }
    child[k] = v
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/7K8aCQdAQs)

Answer (score 2):

While the accespted answer is true, what I've found is that in all situations I've had so far I could just create a complex key instead of nested map.

```
type key struct {
    intKey int
    strKey string
}
```

Then just initiate the map in one line:

```
m := make(map[key]string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Initilize nested map like this:

```
temp := make(map[string]string,1)
temp ["name"]="Kube"
ss.nestedMap [2] = temp
fmt.Println(ss)
```